# Can you plot irreversible but quasi static processes on a $pV$ diagram?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, entropy, reversibility, volume

I've often heard that you can't plot irreversible processes on a  $pV$ diagram, but what about in the case where you have a quasi static process with friction? There still exists a curve of equilibrium states for the system doesn't there?

Comment: If the process consists of a series of equilibrium states, then you can plot these series on a PV diagram, since the PV diagram represents all equilibrium states.

Comment: Yes, if it is quasi static with friction (and the cylinder is adiabatic), then the gas can be considered to undergo a reversible process.  But, to quantify this, you will have to specify what fraction of the frictional heat gets transferred to the gas (e.g., 100%).  For a more detailed discussion of this, see the following thread:  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/thermodynamics-gas-expansion-with-piston-friction.963282/

Comment: @ChetMiller Just to be clear, isn't the process reversible only if 0% of the friction heat gets transferred to the gas?

Comment: @Bob D No.  If the gas alone is considered the system, then the gas experiences a reversible process in which it deforms quasi statically and receives frictional heat "quasi statically."  Such a process is called internally reversible by Moran et al.  We looked specifically at this situation in our thread in the other forum.

Comment: @ChetMiller So, if the process were an adiabatic one, in the sense that the piston and cylinder walls were thermally insulated from the surroundings, then you would treat the friction heating  of the gas as the equivalent of a quasi-static (i.e., reversible) heat transfer from the surroundings?

Comment: @BobD Sure.  As far as the gas is concerned, it is receiving heat from its surroundings.  See posts 19 and 20 of the thread for calculated results for this situation.

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes that is what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: Are you guys saying that the piston itself is outside the system, and therefore the irreversibility of friction is external and not 'seen' by the gas? It makes sense although most places I've seen online include the piston into the system so friction is actual an internal irreversibility. Is it just that the system boundary is arbitrary?

Comment: The "system" is what you define it to be.  It can be gas alone, but it can also be gas plus piston.  This is all looked at separately from both perspectives  in the thread that I provided the link for.